# Multiple template references not working using @ ViewChild in Angular 8

Tags: angular, angular-components, viewchild

In my parent component I have multiple child components. Now I want to access one common function from all the child components. I am doing this by using ViewChild decorator. However I am getting the return value from 1st child component in ViewAfterInit(). But when I am trying to access the second child component, I am getting undefined.

My Parent component .ts file's code

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ViewEncapsulation, ViewChild, AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';
import { NagivationComponent } from '../nagivation/nagivation.component';
import { CensusComponent } from '../your-data/census/census.component';
import { ApplicationComponent } from '../your-data/application/application.component';
import { ExistingPendingCoverageComponent } from '../your-data/existing-pending-coverage/existing-pending-coverage.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-your-data',
  templateUrl: './your-data.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./your-data.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class YourDataComponent implements AfterViewInit{
  @Input() step;

  count:string = 'count1';
  constructor() {

  }
  @ViewChild(CensusComponent, {static: false}) census: CensusComponent;
  @ViewChild(ApplicationComponent, {static: false}) application: ApplicationComponent;
  ngAfterViewInit() {
  console.log('ApplicationComponent:'+ this.application)
    if(this.count === 'count1'){
       this.count = this.census.getSection(); 
    }
    if(this.count === 'count2'){
       this.count = this.application.getSection(); 
    }
  }

}
```

Parent component template file's code

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='setup-content'>
      <h1>Confirm Data/Answer Questions</h1>
      <p>Please answer all questions below. If you have questions about the data provided on this screen, please contact << Broker >> at << Phone >> or << Email >>.</p>
      <div [ngSwitch]=count>
        <app-census *ngSwitchCase="'count1'"></app-census>
        <app-application *ngSwitchCase="'count2'"></app-application>
        <app-existing-pending-coverage *ngSwitchCase="'count3'"></app-existing-pending-coverage>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Here is the stackblitz DEMO link https://stackblitz.com/edit/new-project-zag9um?embed=1&file=app/app.component.html
My question here is why I am getting '**undefined**'

Comment: Can you create stackblitz, reproducing your issue?

Comment: Your stackblitz doesn't have any code that you mentioned in your question.. Please include all relevant code and reproduce your issue in the link..

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to save in stackblitz. Could you please tell me how to do that.

Comment: Go to this stackblitz, https://stackblitz.com/edit/how-to-call-child-componentss-method-from-the-parent-com-rjt2mz  Currently it has only one child called ```child.component.ts``` so you need to click the fork option in top bar and you can include your child component folder as like you mentioned in the question.. After you done with code just click the share option at the top in which you share the first url back here..

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/new-project-zag9um?embed=1&file=app/app.component.html

Comment: The error occurs because you give ```count:string = 'count1';``` in ```your-data.component``` which only loads first ```census component```.. And the ```application component``` doesn't gets called so you are receving undefined.. May I know your exact requirement?? Do you want to load all the components at once??

Comment: No I want application component will load after clicking on getSection function from census component.

Comment: You need to use an event emitter, I edited my answer in order to achieve what you need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For showing the next component after clicking on the button. You need to use an EventEmitter.

EventEmitter is the way to a child component that can communicate to its parent component.

[Angular Event Emitter Docs](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter)

I explain below how to use EventEmitter in this case.

My solution is available here: [Solution on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rj6kwr)

`census.component.ts`

```js
import { Component, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-census',
  templateUrl: './census.component.html',

})
export class CensusComponent  {
  @Output() next: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();

  getSection(){
    // after clicking on getSection we need to emit the value
    // that the parent componente will receive
    this.next.emit('count2'); // <- emit count2
  }

}
```

`your-data.component.html`

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='setup-content'>
      <h1>Confirm Data/Answer Questions</h1>
      <p>Please answer all questions below. If you have questions about the data provided on this screen, please contact << Broker >> at << Phone >> or << Email >>.</p>
      <div [ngSwitch]=count>
        <!-- here app-census pass the value to the parent component
          through onNext method ($event is the string value emitted 
          before)
        -->
        <app-census
          (next)="onNext($event)" *ngSwitchCase="'count1'"></app-census>
        <app-application *ngSwitchCase="'count2'"></app-application>        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`your-data.component.ts`

```js
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-your-data',
  templateUrl: './your-data.component.html'

})
export class YourDataComponent {


  count: string = 'count1';

  onNext(count: string) {
    // parent component receives the value emitted by
    // census component and it stores the value in
    // this.count
    this.count = count;
    // now this.count is count2 and application component will be shown
  }

}
```

Comment: After applying your changes, only last component is getting loaded

Comment: Of course, this.count is count3 at the end, in the HTML of app.componen.ts there is a ngSwitch, this way only the last value will be shown.

Comment: I want to load each of the component on each count. That is what the requirement is. And on each button click the count will change.

Comment: but the code is executing at the same moment, how do you want to show each component at the same time? Maybe you need to add asynchronous code to show at least for 1 sec each component.

Comment: Please check my demo. You will understand the requirement.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and effort. I am very new to angular. So my understanding was not so clear about the various ways to passing data between two components. But now it is clear. Thanks again

Comment: You're very welcome, I'm glad to know I could help you. There are multiple ways to pass data between components. You can use a service as well.

Comment: I am tried that as well, but could not able to do that. I was stuck with this for last 3days. But thanks to you now I can move on. Thank you.